# How to set overlapping static bodies priority?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have a `TileMap` and on top of it a `StaticBody2D` (Slippery) such that the top surface of both exactly overlap like this:

[image]

with the friction on the `StaticBody2D` set to 0 and friction of Tilemap set to 1

so How do I set the priority of the `StaticBody2D` higher than that of the `TileMap` such that any body on top of them only interacts with `StaticBody2D` but not `Tilemap`?

##### "why not just place StaticBody2D above TileMap?"

If I do that then it causes an elevated bump which stops any body from horizontally entering `StaticBody2D`

##### "why not hollow out that portion of the TileMap and place StaticBody2D in it?"

The `StaticBody2D` is generated during runtime and hence the player decides where it is placed making it difficult to modify the tilemap

Comment: I only found priority for areas, sadly.